How to cache Next.js first page load compilation for local development
I'd like to speed up development in my TypeScript Next.js project. I have a script that prefetches an array of pages (currently set to just the index page) on the start of the dev server. Otherwise, the pages wouldn't even start to get compiled until first visited in the browser.
Here is my startDevAndPrefetch.sh script:
#!/bin/bash

# Start timer
start_time=$(date +%s%3N)

# Start the Next.js dev server
yarn devTurbo &

# Get the PID of the last background process
NEXT_PID=$!

# Wait for the server to be ready
wait-on http://localhost:3000

# Run the prefetch script
npx tsx prefetchDevPages.ts

# End timer
end_time=$(date +%s%3N)
elapsed_time=$((end_time - start_time))

echo "Total time: $elapsed_time milliseconds"
echo "You can open http://localhost:3000 now."

# If we weren't running our development server remotely (on Lightsail), we'd call `open http://localhost:3000` to automatically open the browser.

# Wait for the Next.js server process to exit
wait $NEXT_PID

In my package.json, I set yarn dev to call ./startDevAndPrefetch.sh, which runs prefetchDevPages.ts:
// prefetchDevPages.ts

import { BASE_URL } from './constants/config';
import axios from 'axios';

const pagesToPrefetch = ['/'];

async function prefetchPage(page: string) {
  try {
    console.log(`Prefetching ${page}`);
    const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}${page}`);
    console.log(`Prefetched ${page}`);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error prefetching ${page}:`, error);
    return null;
  }
}

async function prefetchAllPages() {
  for (const page of pagesToPrefetch) {
    const response = await prefetchPage(page);
  }

  console.log(`Finished prefetching all ${JSON.stringify(pagesToPrefetch)}.`);
}

prefetchAllPages();


Currently this takes 45-60 seconds.
How could I at least make Next.js cache the compilation such that if there are no changes to any source code since the last time the dev server started, it can start immediately?
E.g. if I run yarn dev and wait 60 seconds and then visit the app in the browser and then kill the dev server and go to lunch and come back and run yarn dev again, why should I need to wait another 60 seconds if no source code has changed?

Quick question, what is the use case of prefetching all the pages at dev time? The only optimization I can think of for your script would be to use Promise.all instead of sequentially awaiting the fetches, but I'd say it wouldn't make much of a difference if currently you're only fetching a single page. You could also try turbopack if the first start takes long.

@moonstar-x I'm already using Turbo. Assume pagesToPrefetch will continue to be just the index page. The point of prefetching is because I know every time I start my server, I'll want to visit the homepage, so I'd rather have it be as ready as possible by the time I visit the browser. I don't want to experience another delay at that time. So what this question is focusing on, though, is how can I avoid re-compiling the same source code. If it hasn't changed at all, it shouldn't matter that the yarn dev server stopped, then started again. yarn dev on subsequent runs should be instant.
